# Iterate through Response<List><KVInfoModel>>>$"{_applicationUris.GranularKVInfo}/{_KVlId}/kv");

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-web-api, microservices

I am trying to iterate through a variable which is set through a response and filter it. I want to filter based on contact type. Is this possible? any suggestions are welcome.

```
//Response class

    public class Response<T> : Response
        {
            public Response();

            public T Content { get; set; }
        }

private async Task<string> GetKVValueAsync()
        {
     var KVContactInformation = await _restServiceClient.GetAsync<Response<List<KVInfoModel>>>($"{_applicationUris.GranularKVInfo}/{_KVlId}/kv");

                List<KVInfoModel> TestList = new List<KVInfoModel>();

                TestList = KVContactInformation.Where(Xyz => xyz.contactType == "Sample");

                return TestList();
}
```

Comment: your question lacks details which is needed for us to answer this question. Without seeing Response class and return type of GetAsync It is impossible to make comment

Comment: I added response class & Return type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
var KVContactInformation = await _restServiceClient.GetAsync<Response<List<KVInfoModel>>>($"{_applicationUris.GranularKVInfo}/{_KVlId}/kv"); 
List<KVInfoModel> testList = KVContactInformation.Content.Where(Xyz => xyz.contactType == "Sample");
return testList;
```